# How to invoke local peripheral device from web script

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am confused about invoking local app from web site.
Is there any way to start an ipad/iphone app from web scripts?  I remember that there is ActiveX with IE which could start a local device such as a camera or printer.  JavaScript could invoke ActiveX.  But there is no activeX in iOS. Here is my problem: How could I start local device from a webpage? Does anyone have the same problem? I have one method but I don't know if it is feasible:

1. UIWebView could execute JavaScript by stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.
2. write a function in a page with JavaScript, which responds to an event on the page (button click, etc.), then change the state.
3. start a thread to inquire the state.  When the state changes , invoke local apps.

Is that possible or any better way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to open your app from Safari browser from you iPad then there is a method to do so. Add the following tags in your app's info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.companyname.appname</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>openApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Save the plist file and now on the web page put `openApp://` in place of the link when user clicks the desired button. This won't be helpful if you try to implement it in your own app in a web view. But it will work from Safari browser from your iPad or from any other app.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thank you,it does work.However, I still want to achieve this in a UIWebView . Is there any possible way?

Comment: Yes you can do so from a web view as well. But you cannot call an App A from App A's webview, as it makes no sense. You will only be able to invoke another app from App A's webview. So, preferable thing would be redirect the web link from your app to safari and then again move back to your app using the aforementioned method.